# Using mat file in C++ program

Tags: c++, matlab

Please. Can any one help me ?

I have Mat file include struct of array for features vectors, I need to use this file in C++ program. How can I load this file in my C++ program?

Answer (score 10):

You could try the [matio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matio/) library. It supports at least up to version 5 mat files (compression and structures I think) and maybe more recent stuff. It seems to be actively developed.

Comment: An example of using matio is here: http://na-wiki.csc.kth.se/mediawiki/index.php/MatIO

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have MATLAB, you can read the [help article](http://www.mathworks.ch/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f39876.html) on their MAT-file API.

Otherwise, there are various open source MAT file readers. If necessary, I'm sure someone can locate them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Modern (since atleast 2006ish) versions of Matlab use the standard HDF5 data format (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) so the HDF5 reference library would be a sensible place to start if a more specific solution doesn't work - many language bindings are available.